# How to select only a few columns of a table

Tags: sql

I have a Table which contain around 1000 columns. When I use

```
Select * 
from Table
```

Its Return entire record of the table. But I just want only limited column of the record.

```
col1        |   col2    |    col3 |   col4   |    col 5  |    ......................... | col1000   |
            |           |         |          |           |    ------------------------- |           |
            |           |         |          |           |    ------------------------- |           |
            |           |         |          |           |    ------------------------- |           |
            |           |         |          |           |    ------------------------- |           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just need col5 to col1000 record data only.

Comment: There's no short-cut here. Either specify `*`, and get all columns, or specify each one you want, from col5 to col1000. (1000 columns indicates a poorly designed database.)

Comment: If you could tag which particular DBMS are you using, you might find a solution involving dynamic SQL with a metadata query that builds your SQL for you.

Comment: Sorry, but 1000 columns sounds like bad table design. I'd recommend to provide a [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 4):

you have to write all the columns that you need in `select`

```
select col5, col6, ......... ,col1000 from table
```

there is no shot-cut way with out it and `select *` means all the columns of your table

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do without typing each column name, one way is using dynamic query.

For example in **SQL Server** you can write the dynamic query like following.

```
DECLARE @selstmt AS NVARCHAR(max);
SET @selstmt = 'select ' + Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Quotename(NAME) FROM 
                ( SELECT c.NAME FROM 
                sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                WHERE t.NAME = 'yourtablename' 
                AND c.NAME NOT IN('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4') 
                )t FOR 
                xml path(''), type).value('.', 
                'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

SET @selstmt = @selstmt + ' from yourtable' 

EXEC sp_executesql   @selstmt
```

Comment: This is a good attempt, I have used xml path in sql server, is it available in others?

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran, I am not really sure, i know it works in sql server. I think i should mention this in answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @PSK for your help. Just help once again how to convert entire query to function or procedure.

Comment: You can't convert to function, but for sure you can create a procedure.

Comment: So Please provide the procedure. Its very help full for me.

Comment: I suggest you better raise another question for this as you are changing the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Specify column names that you want to select instead of using * operator.

`SELECT *` will return all columns for table

`SELECT col5, col6, col7,...., col1000` (col5 upto col1000) will return only specified columns of the table

Answer (score 0):

There actually is one easy way in SSMS.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Select this text, press CNTRL SHIFT Q

Then you have all the columns and can easily remove a few.

Comment: SQL itself has no ctrl-shift.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write all columns.

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table;
```

**But...**

### Tested on MySQL

Since you have too many columns, you can run a query to select the desired columns from the table:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('col1', 'col2', 'col3');

# or to filter the columns
# AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
```

And build the query with the resultant columns.

---

`GROUP_CONCAT` outputs the values in a single row separated with a `,`, so you can use them to query the table directly

Comment: Can you explain the second part of your answer? In which "editor" should one build the query based on `SHOW COLUMNS`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I changed the query, now there is only the column names

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
 col1,col2,col3
FROM
 table_name
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this select the columns `col5` to `col1000`?